# How to disable the cache for django-cms AppHooks?

Tags: python, django, django-cms

I'm working on a page where i have an [event-list page](https://www.villa-falkenhorst.at/veranstaltungen/) (future events) and an [event-review page](https://www.villa-falkenhorst.at/veranstaltungen/archive/) (past events, archive).

On both pages i work with an django-cms AppHook because i also have detail views.

The day after the event the event should be hidden on the event list and visible on the event review page. But the problem is that the event is still in the event-list-page.

models.py

```
# Managers
class EventsManager(models.Manager):
"""EventsManager."""

    def get_all(self):
        return super(EventsManager, self) \
            .filter(is_visible=True) \
            .order_by('-date')

    def get_all_future(self):
        return super(EventsManager, self) \
            .filter(is_visible=True) \
            .filter(date__gte=datetime.datetime.now()) \
            .order_by('date')

    def get_all_past(self):
        return super(EventsManager, self) \
            .filter(is_visible=True) \
            .filter(date__lt=datetime.datetime.now()) \
            .order_by('-date')
```

views.py

```
class EventListView(ListView):
    template_name = 'event_list.html'
    queryset = Events.objects.get_all_future()
    paginate_by = 10

    @never_cache
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(EventListView, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)

class EventArchiveView(ListView):
    template_name = 'event_archive.html'
    queryset = Events.objects.get_all_past()
    paginate_by = 20

    @never_cache
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(EventArchiveView, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(EventArchiveView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['is_arcive'] = True
        return context
```

I tried to use @never_cache but the event is still on the event-list page. I think it's a caching issue but i'm not really sure where to start searching. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I just had a similar problem and it was not a Django CMS related. I encountered the problem only on production for some reason. The solution was to use the class method `get_queryset()` instead of defining my queryset with the `queryset` variable. For some reason when running my django application with UWSGI the sql query got cached and my date filtering got stuck on the date of my first query.

**Replace:**

`queryset = Events.objects.get_all_past()`

**with:**

`def get_queryset(self):
    return Events.objects.get_all_past()`